# Button in WebView to link back to another application Activity

Tags: php, android, webview

I have a little bit of a problem. I need in my first activity to link to an online webpage. I've done this using a WebView. Once my WebView displays the webpage in my activity, there will be a button in the respective online page that will have to link to the next application activity. How will I manage to identify that button (ID) and then make it link to the next activity, which is not a WebView?

I wonder how can this be done and if it has a certain name. It may be done using Php on that page. If some of you find something useful or even a solution to this problem, please help me, and I will surely reward your answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use php to achieve this. In order to make it work you have to add a few things to your Activities intent filter in the manifest. Here is an example intent-filter entry:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="yourwebsite.com"
  android:path="/ActivityName/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then on your web page you can make a link like this:

```
<a href="http://yourwebsite.com/ActivityName/">Goto next Activity</a>
```

When you click the link it should give the users the choice to open it with your application. I would recommend instructing them to check the "Always preform this action with this app" checkbox so that they aren't presented a choice every time.

Note: that the `ActivityName` in the path is not a requirement(it could be anything), but if you have multiple activities that could be getting launched this way using activity name seems like a logical choice to me.

[This website contains another good example.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/web-to-app-interoperability-launch-your-android-app-from-the-web/1011) And an example of how you can send data from the web page to the app.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try it later and will post if something went wrong!